# QB IDS V3 - Errors messages while creating Time Activity

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I face issues while trying to create TimeActivity using QB IDS V3. I sometime get some erros that I really don't know the root cause. the worst is that the TimeActiviy entries sometime get created on Quickbooks but  errors messages are returned. find below some errors messages I get and a sample of my TimeActivity Request

```
Error #1) javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 32; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.]

Error #2) ERROR CODE:6003, ERROR MESSAGE:message=General IO error while proxying request; errorCode=006003; statusCode=500, ERROR DETAIL:null

Error #3) java.net.UnknownHostException: quickbooks.api.intuit.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Error #4) java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

My request is as below:

```
<TimeActivity domain="QBO" sparse="false"  xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TxnDate>2014-02-11</TxnDate>
    <NameOf>Employee</NameOf>
    <EmployeeRef name="Employee Name">2113</EmployeeRef>
    <CustomerRef name="custom Name">1859</CustomerRef>
    <ItemRef name="Database Development">5</ItemRef>
    <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <HourlyRate>0</HourlyRate>
    <Hours>8</Hours>
    <Minutes>0</Minutes>
    <Description>description</Description>
<TimeActivity>
```

i struggle with this issue since long time and the worst is that can't catch the root cause why sometime things work fine and sometime not.
 Can some one help me on that issue

Comment: Can you please share the relamId of your company and raise a support ticket from this link.developer.intuit.com/Support/Incidents


Thanks

Comment: Hi, I raised a support ticket. 00009137. I've provided the realmId in the ticket. please let me know. we have many data inconsistency between what we send, what is really created and response we receive from V3 API

Comment: "Error #1) javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:" is a bug from Java SDK . I've workarounded by using XML. The SDK seems to not support some specials characters such as carriage return character(0x13)

Answer (score 0):

**PN -** QBO US supports ASCII-7 bit and Global supports Unicode.

If service returns anything other than these, then it should be considered as service issue. If I get a workaround then I'll update this post.

Thanks